# How to get Updates list using PackageKit.Transaction interface

Tags: c++, linux, dbus

I want to get Updates list from using `org.freedesktop.PackageKit`
But `org.freedesktop.PackageKit.Transaction` has `GetUpdates` method.
So, i used `PackagetKit.Transaction` but, No such interface 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit.Transaction' on object at path '/org/freedesktop/PackageKit' Error occurred.
I have `/usr/share/dbus-1/interface/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.Transaction.xml`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>

int main() {
    sd_bus_error error = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;
    sd_bus_message *reply = nullptr;

    sd_bus *bus = nullptr;
    int ret = sd_bus_open_system(&bus);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to connect to the system bus: " << strerror(-ret) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }   

    ret = sd_bus_call_method(bus,
                             "org.freedesktop.PackageKit",  
                             "/org/freedesktop/PackageKit", 
                             "org.freedesktop.PackageKit.Transaction",  
                             "GetUpdates",    
                             &error, &reply,
                             nullptr);

    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to call method: " << error.message << std::endl;
        sd_bus_error_free(&error);
        sd_bus_unref(bus);
        return 1;
    }   
    sd_bus_message_unref(reply);
    sd_bus_unref(bus);

    return 0;
}
```